# Compliment & Complement

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

A little confused with the pronunciations of "compliment" and "complement".

Are they distinguished based on the subject of conversation or based on pronunciations?

Is this a good meaning for **compliment** :

> An expression of esteem or approval

Answer (score 1):

Most of this question can easily be answered by looking at a good dictionary. Here is the information that you requested, from the Cambridge Dictionary. Please try to look things like this up yourself before asking a question, and quote the details in your question if the dictionary does not provide a complete answer.

> complement: UK - /ˈkɒm.plɪ.ment/ US - /ˈkɑːm.plə.ment/
>   compliment: UK - /ˈkɒm.plɪ.mənt/ US - /ˈkɑːm.plə.mənt/ - a remark that expresses approval, admiration, or respect

---

Do English speakers use the pronunciation to decide which word it is? I doubt it, as the difference between /e/ and /ə/ is quite small. Furthermore, when compliment is used in the simple past or as a past participle, /-ənt/ will change to /-entəd/. And finally,  complement is not used very often, so some English speakers would not know that there is supposed to be a difference in pronunciation. The context will make the intended meaning clear, though.